# Modern compiler design(chapter 9: convert AST into data dependency graph )

Tags: compiler-construction, circular-dependency, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to understand the algorithm which is used to convert the AST into data dependency graph. However, I don't how does this algorithm deal with the following code:

```
int temp;
temp = a;
a = b;
b = temp;
```

According to the algorithm in the book (Modern Compiler Design 2nd), it will eliminate the local variable of "temp". How can we detect the circular dependencies? I will appreciate any of your help.